# Creating an Angular Global Variable

Tags: angular, typescript

How to create a global variable in Angular?
I created a variable in service, in component login I enter a value after which I access a variable found in service through another component and the value of the variable in service is reset.
What do I need to add or change?

Comment: You should check this nice guide from angular: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Comment: Hey semicolon ! You mean the global variable in the component will be familiar to other components?

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide the service in the highest level module only, this way it will work as a singleton (only one instance shared between components, so the values won't reset),

but you are probably providing it in each of these components so each one is getting a new instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the simple `localStorage` [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if you want also keep the data between page reloads. Depends of your goals one or other approach could be better. 
Also usgin a service, with a very simple code like this (inside a service of course):

```
  saveItemOnStorage(item, key) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
  }

  removeItemFromStorage(key){
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }

  getItemFromStorage(key) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  }
```